# C# and WPF - Implement and display a counter to show the total time an app has been running for

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am a total beginner in C# and WPF. I am trying to write a custom interface to control one of the laser in my lab. The end result would be an executable file (.exe), with various buttons and input fields to set my parameters.

Since the laser requires maintenance after 1,000 hours, I would like to keep track of the total time spent in "emission mode" and display it on the interface to the operator. I would prefer having a clock/counter that is dynamically updated while the laser is in emission mode, showing the total time already elapsed in a hhhh:mm:ss format. Considering the fact that the program might be opened / closed multiple times, I need a way to keep track of the count.

The laser is switched to Emission Mode when a button is clicked. It triggers the function `LaserEmission()`. Laser emission is stopped when the Standy Mode button is clicked and the function `LaserStandby()` is triggered.

My first question is, is this doable and if so, where and how should I keep the total count of the elapsed time spent in emission mode. Is updating a text file with the count every time the laser is switched back to standby mode a viable solution? If so, would the .txt file have to be located in the same directory as my .exe file.

My second question is more related to the implementation of the counter to display a live count in my `timeCount.Content` Label. `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` seems to be the way to do it with WPF.

```
private void LaserEmission(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }


private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I need to take the previous count (txt file?) and update it to display it in timeCount.Content
        timeCount.Content = ...;
    }

private void LaserStandby(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    // Stop the timer, freeze the count, save it and display it.
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Yes, of course, if you want to track the time even between running the program multiple times, you'll need to persist the information outside of the program's in-memory state. Should this be a file, or something else? Depends entirely on your requirements. Do you need any redundancy on the maintenance of the data? Will other processes need access to the data? Even if you use a text file, there's the question of the format. Do you need a structured format such as XML, which is usable by a wide variety of tools? Or maybe a binary file is more appropriate than text

Comment: As for the second question (which should have been its own question...putting multiple questions into a single post also inherently makes the post too broad), yes you can use `DispatcherTimer`. Just make sure you aren't using the `DispatcherTimer` intervals to actually _measure_ the time. In WPF, you can actually use pretty much any timer you want...the timer should update a value to present, in a view model, and WPF will marshal the UI updating logic to the UI thread implicitly for you, assuming you're using normal MVVM/`INotifyPropertyChanged` logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use Serialization. I happened to have a Windows Forms project open, so I used that. Some minor tweaks would be needed to convert to WPF.

We need to create a class to use for serializing our information, which will need an `ElapsedTicks` property to store our data, a static `Load` method to attempt to read the file and return a new `DataStore` object, and a `Save` instance method that will save the current instance to the file from which it was loaded:

```
public class DataStore
{
    public long ElapsedTicks;            
    private string DataFilePath;

    public static DataStore Load(string dataFilePath)
    {
        DataStore dataStore;

        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataStore));
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(dataFilePath))
            {
                dataStore = (DataStore)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            dataStore = new DataStore();
        }

        dataStore.DataFilePath = dataFilePath;
        return dataStore;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataStore));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(DataFilePath))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have a way to load and save our data, we can utilize this in our program. We can create class instances of a `DataStore` to load and retrieve data, a `Timer` for updating the elapsed time, and a `Stopwatch` for measuring the elapsed time:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    private static DataStore dataStore;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    private Stopwatch stopWatch;
```

To update the elapsed time, we would just add the elapsed ticks of the stopwatch to our `dataStore.ElapsedTicks` property, restart the stopwatch if it's running, and update our label with the new value:

```
    private void UpdateElapsedTime()
    {
        dataStore.ElapsedTicks += stopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks;
        if (stopWatch.IsRunning) stopWatch.Restart();
        timeCount.Text = new TimeSpan(dataStore.ElapsedTicks).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff");
    }
```

This method would be called from a few places, starting with the `Form_Load` event, where we first instantiate our objects and hook up the Tick event, then load our data and update the label:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = (int) new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1).TotalMilliseconds;
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Set the path to wherever you want that the user has write permissions
        var dataPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(
            new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Path)), 
            "datastore.dat");

        dataStore = DataStore.Load(dataPath);
        UpdateElapsedTime();
    }
```

The other places it would get called are in the `Tick` event of the timer, and when we start and stop the timer (and stopwatch):

```
    private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the elapsed time in our datastore and display it
        UpdateElapsedTime();            
    }

    private void LaserEmission(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
        stopWatch.Start();
        UpdateElapsedTime();
    }

    private void LaserStandby(object sender, EventArgs e)// RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer, which will freeze the count (which is
        // already displayed), and save our datastore to file.
        timer.Stop();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        UpdateElapsedTime();
        dataStore.Save();
    }
}
```

The first time you run the program, the timer will start from zero. After that, it should start from wherever it last stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution in MVVM hope it helps.

View Part :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Width="175"  Text="{Binding Duree}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10"></TextBlock>
        <Button Command ="{Binding RefreshCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Height="20"> Refresh</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the MVVM Part :

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private RelayCommand _refreshCommand;
        public TimeSpan Duree { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand RefreshCommand => _refreshCommand ??
                                              (_refreshCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => { await Refresh(); }));

        private Task Refresh()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                Duree = DateTime.Now.Subtract(current.StartTime);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Duree);
            });
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to assign DataContaxt, for example in MainWindow Code-behind for exemple :

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }

    }
```